# The force between two sections of uniformly charged line

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coulombs-law

A line is charged uniformly with the linear density $\lambda$ . What is the force between two sections with lenghts $l_{1}$ and $l_2$ if their end points are separated with distance $r_{0}$?

I have calculated that the electric field from the section on the right is: 
$$
E(x)=-k \lambda \frac{l_{2}}{(l_{1}+x)(l_{1}+l_{2}+x)} 
$$

I am not sure how to get the force. I tried: 
$$
dF=E(x)dq=\lambda E(x)dx \Rightarrow F=\int_{0}^{l_{1}}-k \lambda^2 \frac{l_{2}}{(l_{1}+x)(l_{1}+l_{2}+x)} dx
$$
But probably it isn't the right way.

Thank you for any help in advance.

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

propposed solution:

[image]

$$
dF(x_1)= (\lambda dx_1) \int_{l_{1}+r_{0}}^{l_{1}+r_{0}+l_{2}} \frac{\lambda dx_2 }{4\pi \epsilon_0 (x_2-x_1)^2}=k\lambda^2\frac{l_{2}}{(x_{1}-l_{1}-r_{0})(x_{1}-l_{1}-l_{2}-r_{0})}dx_1
$$
The net force: 
$$
F=\int_{0}^{l_{1}} F dx_1=\int_{0}^{l_{1}}k\lambda^2\frac{l_{2}}{(x_{1}-l_{1}-r_{0})(x_{1}-l_{1}-l_{2}-r_{0})}dx_1=k\lambda^2log(\frac{(l_{1}+r_0)(l_2+r_0)}{r_0(l_1+l_2+r_0)})
$$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to consider first the force on a small segment $dx_1$ located at $x_1$ of the first wire due to *all* the pieces on the second wire.  Assuming that by *linear density* you mean $\lambda$ is constant, the small segment at $x_1$ of the first wire will contain charge $dq_1=\lambda dx_1$ so 
$$
dF(x_1)= (\lambda dx_1) \int \frac{\lambda dx_2 }{4\pi \epsilon_0 (x_2-x_1)^2}
$$
The net force is then 
$$
F=\int dF(x_1)\, .
$$
I'll leave it to you to work out the limits of integrations and the actual expressions for the integrals.

Comment: Isn't it identical to my proposition of the solution?

Comment: I end up with a double integral, one over $x_1$ and another over $x_2$.  also the factors are different.  Maybe also I don’t understand your solution so well.

Comment: I think that my expression of E(x) is the solution of your integral.

Comment: Then presumably your $E$ is only the fields on a small section of section on the right,  to the full section as indicate.  (Not denying you are incorrect; just looking to clarify your expressions.)

Comment: ZeroTheHero - I have edited my post acording to your sugestions. Could you please check my solution?

Comment: There is a minor typo in your denominator.  Should be $l_1+l_2+r_0$

Comment: Right, I corrected it. Apart from the typo, is it ok?