# Force of interaction between two charged rods

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coulombs-law

[image]
**Question description:**
The aim is to find the force of interaction between two uniformly positively charged rods whose closest ends are separated by a distance of a units (refer to the picture).

Given:
The linear charge density, λ.
The length of the rods, L.

**My attempt:**
The only way I could think of solving this problem was through double integration since each element of one rod would produce different magnitudes of electric fields at a given distance. 
[image]
But I haven’t been taught how to use double integration yet and this would be a little too complex using it. Is there a way to solve this without double integration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The force between two sections of uniformly charged line](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/365824)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use double integration *as such*. Do one integration at a time. By this I mean find an expression for the field strength due to one rod at a distance $x$ from (say) its midpoint. Then calculate the force on the second rod, knowing the field strength at all points along it due to the first rod. [You will then, in fact, have evaluated the double integral painlessly!]

Answer (score 1):

double integration in a sense is like doing two normal integrations. Find the electric field due to the whole rod on an arbitrary point then integrate to find the total force.